# Issue while connecting WEBIDE to Netweaver GW

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

when I try to connect WEBIDE to Netweaver Gateway by means of destinations I am getting 'Host not found Received status code: "502"'

Could please anyone help me with this?
[image: Destination config]
[image: Response of /IWFND/SG_MED_CATALOG Service]

Comment: is the port accessible for the internet?

Comment: As mentioned above:
Is your URL available on the internet?

Comment: yes,its accessible. I have pasted a screenshot of /IWFND/SG_MED_CATALOG Service in my query